# How to use sp.web to get File metadata along with the file name itself? SPFX

Tags: spfx

This is another way of asking this:
[Trying to get files from a SharePoint library and populate state React/SPFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60509591/trying-to-get-files-from-a-sharepoint-library-and-populate-state-react-spfx)

But it's a different methodology so I believe warrants a different question.

I'm trying to return the contents of an SP document library filled with documents. I want to surface these docs on a list on a web part I've created.

I've used the code in the supplied link, but I'm thinking there has to be a way using sp.web to get the file names and the metadata about that file and be able to store it in state?

Is this a way that works:

```
sp.web.folders.getByName(LibraryName).files.get()..then(function(data){
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my SELECT query, using "*" retrieves all regular fields, "TaxCatchAll/ID,TaxCatchAll/Term" fetches metadata columns, and "File/Name" gathers file information. The expand query is to get the file name and metadata values.

```
await sp.web
  .getFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileServerRelativeUrl)
  .getItem()
  .then((item: any) => {
      return item
        .select("*,TaxCatchAll/ID,TaxCatchAll/Term,FileRef,File/Name")
        .expand("TaxCatchAll,File")
        .get();
  })
  .then(async (resp: any) => {
    console.log("metadata values:",resp)
    console.log("File name:",resp.File.Name)
  });
```

};